# Counterexample to cancellation law in cardinals addition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Charles C.Pinter - Set theory

Let $a,b,c$ be any cardinal numbers.

Give a counterexample to the rule:
$$a+b = a+c  \implies b=c$$

Does there exist a counterexample?

Comment: What is an infinite cardinal plus a finite cardinal?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140930/cardinal-number-subtraction

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{align}&1.\quad\aleph_0=\aleph_0+0=\aleph_0+1\\&2.\quad 0\neq 1\end{align}$$

Where $\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of countably infinite sets, e.g. the non-negative integers, $\mathbb N$.

Comment: This is certainly the very simplest counterexample.

Comment: or any infinite cardinal

Comment: @Greg: Assuming the axiom of choice, yes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: aha, equivalently the well-ordering principle - interesting. Can one construct a counterexample if the axiom of choice isn't assumed?

Comment: @Greg: Indeed. We say that A is a *Dedekind-finite* set if whenever $B\subsetneq A$, $|B|<|A|$. Equivalently this is to say that $|A|<|A|+1$. Every finite set is Dedekind-finite, and assuming the axiom of choice the opposite is also true: Dedekind-finite sets are finite sets. However it is consistent that without the axiom of choice there may be infinite Dedekind-finite sets. These sets may be used to construct such counterexamples.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one: $|\Bbb N| + |\{1\}| =|\Bbb N| + |\{2, 3\}| $, but  $|\{1\}|  \ne|\{2,3\}|$.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably learn later that for any infinite cardinal $a$ the equality
$$a+a=a\cdot a=a$$
holds. This implies that for any infinite cardinal $a$ you have a counterexample $a+a=a+0$.

More generally, if $b$, $c$ are infinite cardinals then
$$b+c=b\cdot c=\max\{b,c\}.$$

The proof of these general result is not that simple, it requires axiom of choice. See e.g. the following questions: [About a paper of Zermelo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/) and [How to prove that from "Every infinite cardinal satisfies $a^2=a$" we can prove that $b+c=bc$ for any two infinite cardinals $b,c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48828/simple-cardinal-arithmetic)

However, showing the above result for some special cases, like $a=\aleph_0$ or $a=2^{\aleph_0}$ is not that difficult and it might be a useful exercise for someone learning basics of set theory and cardinal arithmetic.