# Is it true that for any set non-finite set $S$, $|S \times S| = |S|$?

Tags: set-theory, convex-analysis

If $S$ is a non-finite set, meaning that $|S| \notin \mathbb{N}$, then is it always true that there is a bijection between $S \times S$ and $S$, where $\times$ is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two sets?

It **is** true for $|S| = |\mathbb{N}|$ and $|S| = |\mathbb{R}|$, the first one can be proven by the ["criss-crossing" bijection](https://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/rational-numbers-countable.php) between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.

The second one follows from the bijection between $[0,1[$ and $[0,1[ \times [0,1[$:

If $a \in [0,1[$, then $a = 0.a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5 \dots$ is its decimal expansion with $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,\ldots \in \{0,\dots,9\}$.

With this, we can uniqely build a value in $[0,1[ \times [0,1[$ by considering only its even and only its odd decimal places: $(0.a_1 a_3 a_5 \dots,0.a_2 a_4 a_6 \dots) \in [0,1[ \times [0,1[$, and this process is entirely reversible, therefore

$$|\mathbb{R}| \stackrel{(*)}{=} |[0,1[| = |[0,1[ \times [0,1[| \stackrel{(**)}{=} |\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}|$$

$(*)$ $x \leftrightarrow \tan(2\pi x)$ is a bijection.

$(**)$ Placing the $[0,1[ \times [0,1[$ blocks in a spiral starting from $(0,0)$ towards any direciton gives the bijection.

But is this also true if let's say $|S| = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ or $|S| = \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})), \dots$ (where $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denotes the powerset of $A$), or if $S$ is any other infinite set?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56466/for-every-infinite-s-s-s-times-s-implies-the-axiom-of-choice and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48828/how-to-prove-that-from-every-infinite-cardinal-satisfies-a2-a-we-can-prove

Comment: Instead of write "a set $S$ with $|S|\not\in \Bbb N$" or "a non-finite set" you could just use the word "infinite".

Comment: @jjagmath That depends on how exactly you define "infinite". Or maybe it doesn't. I know there are subtleties here, but I can never remember what they are.

Comment: @Arthur Couldn't find if it was answered yet, but it turns out it is. Thank you!

Comment: @jjagmath I changed it to "non-finite".